# How to select first two columns split by tab from a text file without header in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

The sample data looks like(split by tab):

```
value1  value2  value3  value4
```

I used get-content | format-table to get the data, but don't know how can I get the first two columns (value1 and value2) as their are NO headers to do the select.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Import-Csv` with the `-Header` parameter to define the headers yourself:

```
Import-Csv .\values.txt -Delimiter "`t" -Header col1,col2,col3,col4 |Format-Table col1,col2
```

---

If you want to use `Get-Content`, you can use the `-split` operator:

```
Get-Content .\values.txt |ForEach-Object {
    $col1,$col2,$null = $_ -split '\s+'
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Col1 = $col1
        Col2 = $col2
    }
}
```

`\s+` is regex for "1 or more whitespace characters"